# JQuery Mobile not fit to screen when input focus

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile for Android.

I have 2 inputs on the login page and all is working perfectly, but when I focus an input, the page will not fit to screen and can be horizontal scroll. after unfocus the input box, the page fit to screen again.

unfocus on input box
http://imageshack.us/a/img90/9909/device20121109111004.png

focus on input box, the page have about 2px on right
http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/7078/device20121109111036.png

```
<div data-role="content">
        <form id="loginForm">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" >
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    </div></li>
            </ul>
            <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

how can i fixed this? i want fit to screen when focus on input box
thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your main activity.

Eg:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyAndroidApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyAndroidActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
```

@See [Android activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: i added android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in Androidmanifest.xml, but it not work for me. still can horizontal scroll when focus on input